How to extend an object in Ruby?
Say, I have an object that replies to .hello method. Now, I want to create another object that will reply to both hello (and all other methods of the original object) and bye methods. Something like this (this is pseudo-code!):
x = # original object
y = extend(x) do
  def bye
    # here I can also call methods of the "x" object
    puts "Bye"
  end
end

This new y object is essentially a decorator of x. Is it possible in Ruby?
p.s. I understand how to do this with the help of a new class with the missing_method(), but maybe there is a faster and more compact way?

You mean def y.bye? Or maybe class << y? You'd need to make a copy of x to form y, because otherwise, y will be x.

This might help: What is a singleton class in Ruby?

To create a copy, there's y = x.clone which also copies x's singleton methods. A decorator however isn't a copy, it's more like a wrapper around the original object, see Delegator.
